# OpenSSL: How to narrow the range that Options setting in /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf is applied

Tags: openssl

Recently I upgraded OS of my home server from FreeBSD 13.2-RELEASE to 14.0-RELEASE. And after that I faced the problem that applications running on my home server fail to connect to one of SMTP/IMAP servers that I use.

For example, if I try to connect to the server with `openssl s_client` I get following result.

```
% openssl s_client -host imap.example.net -port 993 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs
CONNECTED(00000003)
00208178CD1D0000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/ssl/statem/extensions.c:894:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 65 bytes and written 330 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1709023219
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
%
```

Using error message "SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled" as crue I made web search and according to the result I understood the problem as following.

1. The problem is related to "SECURE RENEGOTIATION".
2. The error happens when client that supports RFC5746 tries to connect to server that doesn't support it.
3. To connect to such server client need to set SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT option of OpenSSL.
4. By default the option is enabled until OpenSSL 1.1.1 but disabled with OpenSSL 3.0 and later.
5. Version of OpenSSL is 1.1.1 with FreeBSD 13.2-RELEASE and 3.0 with 14.0-RELEASE. So the problem happens after the upgrade of OS.

It seems some applications provide the way to enable SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT option. For example `openssl s_client` enables it by specifing `-legacy_server_connect` command line option, and `stunnel` enables it by adding `options=LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT` in its configuration file. But there are also applications that doesn't provide the way and unfortunately I use such one on my home server.I run web mail application written in PHP. IIUC PHP doesn't provide the way to set options of OpenSSL. So it seems impossible to enable SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT option by the web mail application.

I made further web search and found that the option can be enabled by changing `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` such as following.

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = tls_configuration_sect

[tls_configuration_sect]
system_default = tls_system_default_sect

[tls_system_default_sect]
Options = UnsafeLegacyServerConnect
```

But if I apply the change then SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT is enabled with all outgoing SSL connections from my home server. And it means I'm always exposed to the risk of man-in-the-middle attack.

Then is there any way to narrow the range that SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT option is applied?

Best Regards.

Comment: (0) not programming or development (1) not in the/one file; some programs allow you to specify a different config file, and programs using the default API can be redirected with envvar OPENSSL_CONF (2) you're exposed to MitM _only_ on a server that doesn't implement 5746 (which is probably nothing else you use) _and_ accepts client renegotiation (many didn't even before the Apache attack). OpenSSL (from middle 0.9.8 up) always _offers_ the SCSV and 'unsafeconnect' only affects the handling of a server that _declines_ it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for explanation. I understand I misunderstood the risk of man-in-the-middle attack. So I'll fix the problem by setting  UnsafeLegacyServerConnect in /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.